# Can't type in git bash after I launch subl (windows 8.1 os)

Tags: windows, git, bash

Ok so I set git bash to open sublime text 2 using this 
`echo 'alias subl="C:/Program\ Files/Sublime\ Text\ 2/sublime_text.exe"' >> ~/.bashrc`
When I type `subl` in the bash command line sublime opens as it should. The problem is that once I open it I can't use the bash command line (nothing appears if I type in the command line; well it appears but only after I close sublime text - or I have to close and reopen bash).

Any ideas? I'm very new at git so please explain it like you would explain it to a little child. Thanks

Comment: Are you saying, you lauch sublime from the bash command line?

Comment: Perhaps explain your problem so that we can understand it?

Comment: I type "subl" in the bash command line, sublime text 2 launches but after that I can't use the bash command line unless I close sublime text. Or I have to close bash and open it again

Comment: Try adding a `&` after `sublime_text.exe`

Comment: Ok so now it's working. I'm supposed to create a .txt file using `subl lesson_1_reflections.txt` but it does't work, I get this `$ subl lesson_1_reflections.txt
[3] 2328
sh.exe": lesson_1_reflections.txt: command not found
[3]+  Done                    C:/Program\ Files/Sublime\ Text\ 2/sublime_text.exe`. sublime text launches but doesn't create the text file I asked it to. Any ideas?

Comment: You're now saying run sublime, then run this command lesson_1_reflections.txt. You need to find out how to pass arguments into your alias. I would just use vi for editing on the command line, and leave sublime to itself.