# Git Bash cant run commands after running subl

Tags: git, bash, sublimetext3

So I run `$ subl` and sublime opens, but then my command line goes blank, or infinite, not sure what its called.
example

```
$ subl
|
```

I can type anything i want hit enter, goes to next line and so forth but nothing will actually happen until i close sublime. I've tried the solution from [Can't type in git bash after I launch subl (windows 8.1 os)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28636607/cant-type-in-git-bash-after-i-launch-subl-windows-8-1-os) but adding the `&` after `sublime_text.exe` does not work. `echo 'alias subl="C:/Program\ Files/Sublime\ Text\ 3/sublime_text.exe&"' >> ~/.bashrc`. This used to work perfectly for awhile but out of nowhere it started openning up the SAME file no matter what. Now its just openning up a blank page or whatever I was working on the last time sublime was open. Also just for clarity this is on `windows 10` `gnu bash 4.4.12(1)` and `sublime text 3`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of defining an alias, try instead a script named `subl` that you can set in your `$PATH` (PATH a seen in your bash session)

```
#!/bin/bash
"C:\Program Files\Sublime Text 3\sublime_text.exe" $1 &
```

Then try and type `subl` or `subl aText`.

As the [OP Brandon Benefield](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8083803/brandon-benefield) comments [below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44479901/git-bash-cant-run-commands-after-running-subl/44481165#comment75970913_44481165):

> The solution was after creating a file "`subl`" with the content mentioned above, I moved it to a folder simply named "`bin`" sitting in my home directory.
>   Now typing "`subl`" and "`subl 'file_name.txt'`" works.

Comment: I appreciate the response but sadly I am pretty new to all of this, especially using a command line. It would really help if you could take a moment and elaborate on what exactly it is you're suggesting I do and how to go about it.

Comment: @BrandonBenefield It is about creating a script, making it executable and making sure it is in your PATH. In detail: http://linuxcommand.org/wss0010.php

Comment: I want to thank the both of you for your help. The solution was after creating a file "subl" with the content from VonC, I moved it to a folder simply named "bin" sitting in my home directory. now typing "subl" and "subl 'file_name.txt'" works. You were both very helpful.

Comment: @BrandonBenefield Well done! I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.